# Could the Ion cannons of the Tollans penetrate the shield/defense technology of the Asgard?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Is there any discussion in any episode or series to help contrast the power of the Tollan versus the power of the Asgard.

In particular how powerful the Tollan [Ion Cannons](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ion_Cannon) are compared to Asgard ships and their shield technology.

It's shown that a single shot can take out the Goa'uld Ha'tak class ships.

Comment: What's with the funky capitalization of Asgard?

Comment: Good question, not sure why I typed it like that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was stated in an episode commentary that the Ori pulse cannons are ion-based, just as the Tollan's ion cannons are. Since the Ori weapon is unable to penetrate Asgard shields, it seems unlikely that they would fall to a Tollan weapon that operated on the same principles. So, in Tollan Ion Cannons VS Asgard ships and shields, the Asgard would almost certainly emerge as the victors.

While we never see Tollan and Asgard technology pitted against each other, it is probably safe to assume that the Asgard are more technologically advanced than the Tollan. They are clearly much much older than the Tollan, who are descended from an Earth culture even though they've surpassed us technologically, and judging by the development of new weapons to use against the replicators and the Ori, they have clearly continued to progress all this time.

Comment: We do, however, see Asgard vs Ori in the same battle of the supergate where the Russian ship RFS Korolev was destroyed (Episode "Camelot").  The Asgard ship's fate is not clear, though it is implied it met the same fate as the Korolev.  It's pilot, Kvasir, did survive.  That would seem to me to say that the Asgard vs Tollan would at best be a draw, not a clear Asgard victory.

Comment: @BBlake - The Ori have far more advanced weaponry than the Tollan, though. The ion-based pulse weapons are a secondary weapons system, which they used to grab the Ha'taks that evaded fire from their main cannon. We did see in Camelot that those particular ion-based weapons had little to no effect on Asgard shields.

Answer (score 2):

The asgard are considerably more advanced than the tollan, it is unclear whether the asgard ever made their own stargates but it is more than likely they would have been able to, considering the tollans have the intellectual capacity as any other human (being they are just human) the asgard intellect is far beyond any other known race which has allowed them to create such advanced technology, by the time they destroyed themselves there technology was about on the same level as that of the ancients, their plasma beam weapons offered unparalleled combat superiority to any known space faring civilization, including the ancients, also take into account that the ancient were around for over 50 million years and the asgard managed to reach their level of technology in only 100,000 years. So while tollan technology is very impressive i believe the asgard would would swamp them , because also the tollans didnt really have a military they relied solely on their ground based ion cannons while i believe they would be effective at combating asgard ships the simply do not have the resources to hold out for very long

Answer (score 0):

The huge Tollan Ion Cannons are no match for Asgardian shield technology, which are the only shields known to resist Ancient drones! Both the Tollans and the Asgard are peaceful races, but Tollana would be completely defenseless against Asgardian vessels. Their ion cannons could fire as many charged particle streams, but they would just impact the impervious Shields.

Comment: All shields will fail eventually.  And there are enough ion cannons on the surface of Tollana that i'm sure the Tollans have the technology to coordinate and focus the fire of the cannons with possible firing solutions.  Also, remember that the Tollans have made their own Stargate, which is not something I'm aware of the Asgard doing.